# Pair the elements in an array by two's then find the difference and sum

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have this array

```
$number = [2,1,4,3,6,2];
```

1. First pair the elements on an array by two's and find their difference
   so this is the output in the first requirement

   ```
   $diff[] = [1,1,4];
   ```
2. Second sum all the difference
   this is the final output

   ```
   $sum[] = [6];
   ```

Conditions:

1. the array size is always even
2. the first element in a pair is always greater than the second one, so their is no negative difference

What I've done so far is just counting the size of an array then after that I don't know how to pair them by two's. T_T

Is this possible in php? Is there a built in function to do it?

Comment: I tried to understand your question but got `E_PARSE_ERROR` from my brain

Comment: One method would be to use a 2-step for loop: e.g. `for($i=0,$c=count($numbers);$i<$c;$i+=2)`

Comment: `array_chunk` will group an array by 2's, but it's probably overkill for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line:

```
$number = [2,1,4,3,6,2];
$total = array_sum(array_map(function ($array) {
    return current($array) - next($array); 
}, array_chunk($number, 2)));
echo $total;
```

Comment: Might want an abs() in there to handle cases like `$number = [1,2,4,3,2,6];` but otherwise a neat solution

Comment: @MarkBaker OP has stated `"the first element in a pair is always greater than the second"`

Comment: Ah, OK, missed that... but still a neat solution

Comment: this is one is working, base on the votes I think this is the best one. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine:

```
<?
$number = array(2,1,4,3,6,2);
for($i=0;$i<count($number); $i+=2){
    $dif[] = $number[$i] - $number[$i+1];
}
print_r($dif);
$sum = 0;
foreach ($dif as $item){
    $sum += $item;
}
echo 'SUM = '.$sum;
?>
```

[Working CODE](http://codepad.org/aH8QTpcX)

Answer (score 1):

Well with your conditions in mind I came to the following

```
$number = [2,1,4,3,6,2];
$total = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i+=2) {
    $total += $number[$i] - $number[$i + 1];
}
```

Comment: He wants to sum the differences, not the averages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the different stages kept,

```
$numbers = [2,1,4,3,6,2];
$diff = [];
for($i=0,$c=count($numbers);$i<$c;$i+=2)
{
    $diff[] = $numbers[$i]-$numbers[$i+1];
}
$sum = array_sum($diff);
```

Else, to just get the total and bypass the diff array:

```
$numbers = [2,1,4,3,6,2];
$total = 0;
for($i=0,$c=count($numbers);$i<$c;$i+=2)
{
    $total += $numbers[$i]-$numbers[$i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check and see if this works for you.

```
    <?php        
    $sum=0;
    $number = array(2,1,4,3,6,2);
    for ($i=0;$i<=count($number);$i++) {
    if ($i%2 == 1 ) {  
        $sum = $sum + $number[$i-1] - $number[$i];
    }
    }

    print $sum;
    ?>
```

Comment: Why hard-code `$max_elements` instead of using `count($number)`?

Comment: There are many improvements needed for this code - I'd suggest looking at my answer for a more efficient implementation of a for loop. Hopefully you can learn yourself, and improve your code as well as the OP

Comment: <?php $max_elements=6; $sum=0; $number = array(2,1,4,3,6,2);      for ($i=0;$i<=count($number);$i++) { if ($i%2==1) { $sum = $sum + $number[$i-1] - $number[$i]; } } print $sum; ?>

Comment: sorry! I agree count is the right thing also i changed to include i%2==1 to check if this is odd-- this my first reply in php on forums :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    $number = array(2,1,4,3,6,2);

    $diff = array();
    $v3 = 0;
    $i=1;
    foreach($number as $val){
    if ($i % 2 !== 0) {
        $v1 = $val;
    }
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        $v2 = $val;
        $diff[] = $v1-$v2;
        $v3+= $v1-$v2;       
        }
    $i++;
    }
    print $v3;//total value
    print_r($diff); //diff value array
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got this far it gives the required solution.

```
$arr = array(2,1,4,3,6,2);
$temp = 0;
$diff = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key % 2 == 0) {
        $temp = $value;
    }
    else {
        $diff[] = $temp - $value;
    }
}

print_R($diff);
print 'Total :' . array_sum($diff);
```

Note : Please update if any one knows any pre-defined function than can sorten this code.